# Scheme rotation function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function in Scheme that returns all rotations of a given list. For example, (rotate '(a b c d e)) should return ((a b c d e) (b c d e a) (c d e a b) (d e a b c) (e a b c d)) (in some order).

I am not sure this would work:

```
(define (make-rotate alphabet) (lambda (x) (+ x alphabet)))
(define (same-arg-twice fn) (lambda (arg) (fn arg arg)))
(define (flip fn) (lambda (a b c d e) (fn b c d e a) (fn c d a e b) (fn d e a b c) (fn e a b c d)
(define (flip fn)

(lambda (3 9 5 8 2 4 7) (fn 9 4 3 2 4 7 8) (fn 3 2 4)
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what those functions could have to do with the problem, but it looks like you need to review the fundamentals of Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (rotate lst)
  (for/list ((_ lst))
    (let ((tmp lst))
      (set! lst (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst))))
      tmp)))
```

```
> (rotate '(a b c d e))
'((a b c d e) (b c d e a) (c d e a b) (d e a b c) (e a b c d))
```

## or:

```
(define (one-rotate lst)
  (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst))))

(define (rotate lst)
  (for/list ((_ lst))
    (let ((tmp lst))
      (set! lst (one-rotate lst))
      tmp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a function that rotates a list once.
That is, it takes the list's first element and puts it at the back instead.

```
(define (rotate-once ls)
  (append (cdr ls) (list (car ls))))
```

Test:

```
> (rotate-once '(a b c))
'(b c a)
```

Looks good.

Now we can use this on an already rotated list to produce the next rotation.

```
> (rotate-once (rotate-once '(a b c)))
'(c a b)
```

We could almost write this recursive procedure

```
(define (rotate ls)
  (if (...)
      '()
      (cons ls (rotate (rotate-once ls)))))
```

but there is no useful condition for terminating the recursion.

We could depend on the length of the list, but I did this instead: make a helper function and pass it the list of elements that haven't been moved around yet.
When that list is empty, we're done.

```
(define (rotate-helper ls remaining)
  (if (null? remaining)
      '()
      (cons ls (rotate-helper (rotate-once ls) (cdr remaining)))))
```

and now we can define

```
(define (rotate ls) (rotate-helper ls ls))
```

and

```
> (rotate '(a b c d e))
'((a b c d e) (b c d e a) (c d e a b) (d e a b c) (e a b c d))
```